# Postgres: Is it OK to create a materialized view based on another materialized view?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working in Postgres 9.4. Is it OK to create a materialized view based on another materialized view?

It doesn't seem to produce any errors:

```
# create materialized view vw_county as select * from domes_county;
SELECT 40
# create materialized view vw_county_meta as select * from vw_county;
SELECT 40
```

I guess when I update the database, I need to be careful to update the materialized views in the correct order.

But is there anyother  reason why it might be dangerous?

Comment: Apart from the dependencies (that you are well aware of) I don't see any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a MV using another MV.
But the main problem lies when u try to refresh the newly created MV.
You may face issues while refresh using fast method.